# Failed to locate symbol __aeabi_memset in Android application

Tags: android, cross-compiling

I cross-compiled an application with CMake, generating a *.so* file for ARM v7 that is later included in an Android project:

```
cmake ../src -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK="/opt/android-ndk-r13b"
```

When I create the APK file and upload it to the mobile phone. The application fails to start, producing the following message:

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memset" referenced by
"/data/app/org.qtproject.example/lib/arm/libexample.so"
```

It seems that *libc* contains *__aeabi_memset*, but I am currently loading this library in the loader. What could be calling this function?

I tried by downgrading the SDK to the 22 API:

- Android SDK build tools 23.0.1
- Android 5.1.1 (API 22)
- CMake 3.7.2.

Comment: I have same problem but only with devices on MTK6580 platform with Android 6.0. Did you find how-to fix this problem?

Comment: I was including in the Android project a static library that was compiled with a different Android NDK version. The problem was solved by compiling everything with the same NDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After some testing I found solution for me, maybe it will be helpful for you or somebody else. My native library stops crashing with UnsatisfiedLinkError:  dlopen failed:
cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memset" after I rebuilt it with Android-NDK version 10.